# Where to find the bus schedules for Charleroi airport to Charleroi train station?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses

I will be traveling to Charleroi and then by train to Liege.

I am trying to find the schedule for the buses and the ticket prices, but I have been unable to find them. I tried using the train planning tool which also gives some bus schedules, but for now I don't know if the plane is on time and if this system covers all possible buses.

**Where to find the bus schedules for Charleroi airport to Charleroi train station?**

Are there alternatives to get to Liege?

Answer (score 6):

This turned out to be harder than I expected. The bus between the airport and the railway station is operated by [TEC](https://www.infotec.be/) and you can find the info on their website. Unfortunately the website is only available in French and German and I couldn't find a pdf with the schedule to link to.

So here it goes to find the schedule:

- On the homepage you have a big box under the title "Horaires et plans de ma ligne" and the phrase "Numéro et/ou nom de la ligne"
- This box is asking for the name or number of the line that you care about. It happens to be line A, so you just type "A".
- A lot of choices appear one of which (the third at the moment) is "A CHARLEROI Sud - GOSSELIES Airport".
- That is the one you need, so you select it and click the big red button "Détails de ma ligne".
- This gives the times for the next departures. You probably don't care about now, but want some date and time in the future. In red, there is written "Modifier". This means "Modify" and clicking it will allow you to change the date and time. To change the direction of travel, you can click the well-known symbol with arrows to the left and the right. At least something is visually intuitive.

The price for this bus is at the moment 6 euro.

The only real alternative would be taking the [shuttle to Brussels](https://www.brussels-city-shuttle.com) and take the train there. It is certainly faster and maybe cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to about any "how do I get from here to there using public transport" question can be found on the Belgian Railway's website.

https://www.belgiantrain.be/en

The trip planner on that site can plan trips for you between any two points in the country. It understands addresses, station and bus stop names, and POI's.

So you just enter "Charleroi Airport" in the "from" field, wherever you want to go to in Belgium (or Europe) in the "to" field. Add time and date, and presto, you're set.

Such comprehensive public transport planners are actually rather common in Europe,  but depending on where you come from you may indeed not be used to such planners being available, or indeed being comprehensive.

In the case of Belgium however the planner can be trusted. And it will reliably tell you how to get from Charleroir Airport to Liège.

Comment: It appears from the Internet Archive that [www.belgiantrain.be did not exist until the middle of 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.belgiantrain.be/), which explains why the answer from 2017 didn't refer to it.  But now that that website does exist, this answer is probably better.  +1

Comment: It actually did exist in 2017, but under a different URL. A comprehensive trip planner has been available for some time. You could access the same data on the websites of "De Lijn" and "TEC" as well...
It is clear from the question that the OP found this site "used train planning tool which also gives some bus schedules"
But for some it is incredible that one planner would have everything...

Comment: Does this includes services like flixbus or other dedicated routes to the airport or aren those considered public transport?